# synonymize tags: 'dhcpd' & 'dhcp-server', and 'isc-dhcp' with 'isc-dhcpd'

Tags: support, retag-request

Please merge the following tags:

- Make [dhcpd](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dhcpd) a synonym of [dhcp-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dhcp-server).
- Make [isc-dhcp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/isc-dhcp) a synonym of [isc-dhcpd](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/isc-dhcpd). I just manually cleaned up some posts.

Answer (score 1):

[dhcpd](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dhcpd) is actually already a synonym of [isc-dhcpd](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/isc-dhcpd) (whether or not this is ideal is something we can debate - I think it makes more sense to point it at dhcp-server myself, but merging [isc-dhcpd](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/isc-dhcpd) with [dhcp-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dhcp-server) may not be the most correct thing to do).

---

The second synonym idea ([isc-dhcp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/isc-dhcp) -> [isc-dhcpd](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/isc-dhcpd)) already exists (someone beat me to it or it was already there?).
Honestly it should probably go the other way around -- the ISC DHCP reference implementation is both a client and a server, and someone could be asking a question about either component...